# MySQL 'AS' modifies selection

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok I am lost, I have no idea why those both querys have different output.

```
The table looks something like this:
+------------+--------+--------+
|    date    | kills  | deaths |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2016-05-03 | 123456 | 123456 |
+------------+--------+--------+

SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(),30), `kills`, `deaths` 
    FROM `bf4c_1558544842`
    WHERE `date` <= SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(),30) 
    ORDER BY `date` DESC 
    LIMIT 1

SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(),30) AS "date", `kills`, `deaths` 
    FROM `bf4c_1558544842`
    WHERE `date` <= SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(),30) 
    ORDER BY `date` DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```

The only difference is the `AS "date"`, but why does that change the selection ? 
The first gets me the intended first after the given border and the second gives me the last in the table.

Could pleas someone explain me why this happens ?

Thanks in advance, Feirell.

Comment: because the `date` in the 2nd order by clause refers to `subdate(current_date(), 30)`

Comment: But why wold that change the outcome when there is only one result ?

Comment: @Feirell because there is more than 1 result, they are sorted and only then truncated via limit

Comment: @Fabricator . . . You should elaborate your comment into an answer.

Comment: Because the first statement orders by column `\`date\`` and picks the first one while the 2nd statement orders by `SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(),30)` and _then_ picks the first one. Different order, different 1st row.

Comment: @Lashane ohh that seems reasonable, how would I have to write the query for the right result and the renaming ?

Comment: One more example why column names with reserved words yield surprising results.

Comment: @Feirell don't use the same name for table's columns and for calculated ones, use `as currentDateMinus30` for example

Comment: Oh well thats a shame but thanks for your help and your detailed explanation ! I really appreciate it !

Comment: @Feirell If you want to keep your aliased column name as date, change your ORDER BY clause to say ORDER BY `bf4c_1558544842`.`date' to specify you want to order by the table's date not your aliased column.

Comment: @KyleHale Wonderful ! Thank you very much ! Could you pleas put that as an own answer so I can select it is a the correct answer ?

Comment: @PerlDog `date` is not a reserved word. I'm getting tired of people claiming that.

Comment: @Barmar Uhh, really? Then I'm sorry. I'd bet that. But the result is surprising nonetheless.

Comment: @PerlDog If you use a reserved word as a column or alias, you get a syntax error, not "surprising results". This problem is just because his alias was the same as a table column, nothing related to keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the second query the expression `SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(),30)` is aliased as `date`. Later on, the selected rows are `ORDER BY date` and after the sort only the first row is returned.

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) of the `SELECT` statement explains:

> A `select_expr` can be given an alias using `AS` ***alias_name***. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses.
>
> ...
>
> MySQL resolves unqualified column or alias references in `ORDER BY` clauses by searching in the ***select_expr*** values, then in the columns of the tables in the `FROM` clause.

This basically means that aliases have higher priority than column names.

There is a column named `date` in the table. In the first query, `ORDER BY date` uses it for sorting and you get the results you expect.

On the second query, the `date` alias is used by the `SORT BY date` clause. But since it aliases the constant expression `SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(),30)` all the selected rows have the same value for the `date` expression. They are already sorted, no matter what their order is. Any result is possible in this case.

Edit: 
A solution would be to add the table name in front of the `date` in the order by clause like this:

```
SELECT SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(),30) AS "date", `kills`, `deaths` 
    FROM `bf4c_1558544842`
    WHERE `date` <= SUBDATE(CURRENT_DATE(),30) 
    ORDER BY `bf4c_1558544842`.`date` DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```

This way the interpreter knows that the column is meant not the new alias.